# Carrierwave upload and extract zip before save rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I want to upload a zip file contains documents and after uploading it to server I want to extract those on server. 
I have used Carrierwave Gem to upload zip file code is below for that :

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
   # storage :fog
   # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
   # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
 def store_dir
   "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
 end
 def extension_white_list
  %w(zip)
  #%w(pdf doc htm html docx)
 end
end
```

No what I want to know that which Gem can help me to achieve the extraction part and where that code will be placed in this uploader class or anywhere else.. I'm very new to this rails stuff so if this question require anything more pls do let me know.

Comment: Try to use [rubyzip](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip) gem for file unzipping.

Comment: Thanks for quick response .. I looked into this gem.. but where should I place the code for unzipping .. here in this uploader class I don't see any path or variable which contain the state/location for the zipped file ..

Comment: If you can update the server you can install a tool such as unzip.
And just run this command from the rails server or a background worker \`unzip file_path\`  in a custom carrier wave processor

Comment: can't install anything on server :(

Comment: You could just extract these files in the controller, and then send opened files (using `File.open`) as an attachment to your record.